# Using React, how to grab data from JSON in API - object of arrays

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I'm currently using this API https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/countries to practice grabbing data. I'm trying to select, have an option drop down where I can select a country (and also grab country code (iso3) for value/key) and then display stats (e.g. confirmed, recovered, etc.).

Using console.log, I get back:

```
{countries: Array(188)}
 countries: (188) [{…}, {…}, …]
 __proto__: Object
```

Where countries seem to be an object with nested arrays and objects inside:

```
{countries: Array(188)}
 countries: Array(188)
  [0 … 99]
  [100 … 187]
```

I'm currently trying to grab countries then map both arrays: `[0 ... 99]` and `[100 ... 187]`, so that at the end I can dynamically render a drop down option list (`<select>` + `<option>`) of country names using data e.g.: `{name: "Afghanistan", iso2: "AF", iso3: "AFG"}` and select a country and see stats of selected country.

In React render:

```
  return (
    <div>
      <select>
        {grabbingData.map(([country, code]) => (
          <option key={code} value={countries.iso3[code]}>
            {country}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
```

With `console.log(countries.countries[187])`, I'm able to grab `{name: "Zimbabwe", iso2: "ZW", iso3: "ZWE"}`, but I'm unable to render the select option drop down list with country names.

Comment: May you double check your destructing in the map is correct?

Comment: I was able to grab a country using console.log, but having trouble rendering the drop down option list with name of countries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are destructing the country as `array` instead of an `object` inside your `map`.

Also, I don't understand the `value` for your each `option`. I supposed you want to set each `value` to be an `object`? If yes, you wouldn't want to do that.

I suggest you do it this way.

```js
...

function onChange(event) {
  const { value } = event.target;
  const selectedCountry = countries.find(({ iso2 }) => iso2 === value);

  console.log(selectedCountry);
}

return (
  <div>
    <select onChange={onChange}>
      {countries.map((country, i) => (
        <option key={i} value={country.iso2}>
          {country.name}
        </option>
      ))}
    </select>
  </div>
);
```

[image: Edit kind-shadow-uwez5]

---

If you want to get the stat for the selected country, you have to include what API to use on you question. Currently the API you mentioned only returns `countries`.